# "No route matches" error in rspec, but route shows up in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

Here is my route from `routes.rb`:

```
resources :books, :except => [:new, :edit] do

    post "pull" => "books#update", :data => { "pull" => true }
```

`rake routes` shows things as expected

```
pull_api_v1_book POST  /api/v1/books/:id/pull(.:format)  
    api/v1/books#update {:format=>:json, :data=>{"pull"=>true}}
```

Running a dev server, the route works as expected:

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books/3/pull?auth_token=1234567890
```

My spec in in books_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe "pull api" do
  it "should not fail" do
    post :pull, params: { :id => 12 }
  end
end
```

But the output of the spec:

```
 Failure/Error: post :pull, params: { :id => 12 }

 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"pull", :controller=>"api/v1/books", :id=>12}
```

Why can't rspec find the route?

Comment: Can you paste in the spec, for reference that will be helpful.

Comment: Its there (very simple one line spec). I made it a little more obvious now. `post :pull, params: { :id => 12 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller tests in rails don't actually invoke the routing, it's only syntactic sugar for calling the controller action. Your spec should call:

```
post :update, params: { :id => 12 }
```

If you actually want to test the route you should use a request spec.